# Find $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+2)} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am doing the telescoping technique with partial sum of this infinite series because I want to find an upper bound of its partial sum.
 \begin{equation} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+2)}
\end{equation} 
First I set $ \frac{1}{n(n+2)}= \frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+2}$ and solve to get $A=\frac{1}{2}$  and  $B=-\frac{1}{2}$.
So I'm finding $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+4})$
and proceed with the partial sum expansion.
At the end I am left with $S_N=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2N+4}$ by cancelling terms in between and then $\lim_{N \to \infty}S_N=\frac{3}{4}$.

Am I doing it correctly? Thank you for your time.

Comment: [yep](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(1%2F(n(n%2B2)),+n%3D1..infinity))

Comment: Thanks @tilper.

Comment: Check again on your partial sums. I think you missed another negative term (though it tends to zero).

Comment: Yeah I know I am missing a negative term because it cancels with a positive one in the following second pair of parentheses but I can always cancel while tending to infinity and it gets reallyyyy small. Thank you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\bigg]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\bigg)\bigg]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg] = \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Sorry but did you read the question? (The same would go for four upvoters...)

Answer (score 2):

In case you're interested, you can also compute this series using a certain representation of the digamma function $\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{z}{n(n+z)}$. We are then looking for $\frac{\psi(3)+\gamma}{2}$. Using the following integral representation of the digamma function,
$$\psi(s+1)=-\gamma+\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^s}{1-x}\,dx$$
we find that $\psi(3)=-\gamma+\frac{3}{2}$.
 Your sum is then 
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n(n+2)}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time but I have not reached this level of mathematics yet so I don't have a clue about this way. But thank you though.